# Interacting with Epub using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, publishing, epub

I am new to the Epub3 environment. I am trying to implement some simple javascript in my Epub3. I have searched through internet for any resources but didn't get anything clear.

I am just calling a function 'onchange' on my input text box. But unfortunately this function was not being called in my epub.

Please guide me to implement the same. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>

<head>

  <title>Unknown</title>
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="page_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body class="calibre">

  <div>

    <p>Correct the 5 mistakes underlined in the text.</p>

  </div>

  <div>

    <ol>

      <li>The two maps <u>allows</u> us to see the changes in one small town over a 300-year period. </li>
      <li>In the 1700s, the town was relatively small and <u>consists</u> of a few farms and houses gathered around a central market place and church.</li>
  <li>Transport <u>restricted</u> to horses at that time so the roads were very basic. Having said that, the roads were clearly marked and the river had a bridge running across it.</li>
  <li>
    In the present-day town, a great deal <u>changing</u>. Perhaps the most noticeable changes are those relating to transportation.
  </li>
  <li>
    Our modern-day needs are very different and so the roads <u>are improving</u> and
  </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
<p>Correct Transformation</p>
<div><ol><li>
  <input type='text' onchange="Ip1Func()"/>
</li><li>
  <input type='text'/>
</li><li>
  <input type='text'/>
</li><li>
  <input type='text'/>
</li><li>
  <input type='text'/>
</li></ol></div>
<div id="TextOP"><span>First span</span></div>


<script>
<![CDATA[
function Ip1Func()
  {
   var rDiv = document.getElementById('TextOP');
   //alert('hi');
   var result = document.createElement('span');
   var message = document.createTextNode('Hello Epub. Your are new to me.');
   result.appendChild(message);
   rDiv.appendChild(result);   
  }
]]>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What reader are you viewing the ePub in?? For most readers, you don't need the "<![CDATA[" tag...

Comment: I just tried to view the output in Calibre tool but didn't check it any reader. Also when I add the script as a external .js file it worked.

Comment: I am guessing this is the problem... I'm not sure how supportive the Calibre tool is of ePub3. Try checking the exported ePub in Readium or iBooks!